Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0 - Text Classification
I use 'bert-base-uncased' model. I fine-tuned my dataset using BERT model and saved it in my Drive. Then I load the trained model and test it.
This is my BERTClass
class BERTClass(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BERTClass, self).__init__()
        #initialize layers
        self.bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', return_dict=True)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(768, 6)

    def forward(self, input_ids, attn_mask, token_type_ids):
        output = self.bert_model(
            input_ids,
            attention_mask=attn_mask,
            token_type_ids= token_type_ids
        )
        output_dropout = self.dropout(output.pooler_output)
        output = self.linear(output_dropout)
        return output

model = BERTClass()
model.to(device)

This is how I load my trained model:
model_trained = BERTClass()  # This is the correct line to use your trained model class
model_trained.load_state_dict(torch.load("drive/ColabNotebooks/BERT_Trained_Model/best_model_path"), strict=False)

Then I input some example and test it
example = 'hi'
encodings = tokenizer.encode_plus(
    example,
    None,
    add_special_tokens=True,
    max_length=MAX_LEN,
    padding='max_length',
    return_token_type_ids=True,
    truncation=True,
    return_attention_mask=True,
    return_tensors='pt'
)
model_trained.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    input_ids = encodings['input_ids'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)
    attention_mask = encodings['attention_mask'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)
    token_type_ids = encodings['token_type_ids'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)
    output = model_trained(input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids)
    final_output = torch.sigmoid(output).cpu().detach().numpy().tolist()
    # print(train_df.columns[1:].to_list()[int(np.argmax(final_output, axis=1))])
    print(final_output)

So I got this error:
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-aa3317f07ac8> in <cell line: 17>()
     19     attention_mask = encodings['attention_mask'].to(device)
     20     token_type_ids = encodings['token_type_ids'].to(device)
---> 21     output = model(input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids)  # Don't move the output here
     22     final_output = torch.sigmoid(output).cpu().detach().numpy().tolist()
     23     # print(train_df.columns[1:].to_list()[int(np.argmax(final_output, axis=1))])

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2235         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   2236         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2237     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2238 
   2239 

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument index in method wrapper_CUDA__index_select)

How I fix this issue?
I saw some answers for this type questions. Most are says move the model to 'cuda'. I tried it but not works. What can I do?

Can you please add the output of:
for n,p in model_trained.named_parameters():     print(f"{n}: {p.device}")
